# How do you find values like 0x000000 for definitions in C++?

Tags: c++, definition, game-development

I am editing some files of a video game and there is a function called `battle_check_target` which determines who the player can attack.

```
battle_check_target

//which has these definitions set for it

    BCT_NOONE       = 0x000000, ///< No one
    BCT_SELF        = 0x010000, ///< Self
    BCT_ENEMY       = 0x020000, ///< Enemy
    BCT_PARTY       = 0x040000, ///< Party members
    BCT_GUILDALLY   = 0x080000, ///< Only allies, NOT guildmates
    BCT_NEUTRAL     = 0x100000, ///< Neutral target
    BCT_SAMEGUILD   = 0x200000, ///< Guildmates, No Guild Allies

    BCT_ALL         = 0x3F0000, ///< All targets

    BCT_WOS         = 0x400000, ///< Except self (currently used for skipping if src == bl in skill_area_sub)
    BCT_GUILD       = BCT_SAMEGUILD|BCT_GUILDALLY,  ///< Guild AND Allies (BCT_SAMEGUILD|BCT_GUILDALLY)
    BCT_NOGUILD     = BCT_ALL&~BCT_GUILD,           ///< Except guildmates
    BCT_NOPARTY     = BCT_ALL&~BCT_PARTY,           ///< Except party members
    BCT_NOENEMY     = BCT_ALL&~BCT_ENEMY,           ///< Except enemy
    BCT_ALLY        = BCT_PARTY|BCT_GUILD,
    BCT_FRIEND      = BCT_NOENEMY,
    BCT_CLAN        = BCT_SAMECLAN|BCT_CLANALLY ///< **What I added**
```

The player, an enemy, your guild, your party etc.

There is also a system called clans in the game which work like guilds and parties. Clans have clanmates and clan allies just like guilds. They can not attack each other though which is why I want to add the clan definitions like so:

```
BCT_SAMECLAN    = 0x300000, ///< Clanmates
BCT_CLANALLY    = 0x280000, ///< Clan allies
```

And then put them in the conditional statement which determines who can attack who:

```
if( !state ) //If not an enemy, nor a guild, nor party, nor yourself, it's neutral.
        state = BCT_NEUTRAL;
    //Alliance state takes precedence over enemy one.
    else if( state&BCT_ENEMY && strip_enemy && state&(BCT_SELF|BCT_PARTY|BCT_GUILD|**BCT_CLAN**) )
        state&=~BCT_ENEMY;

    return (flag&state)?1:-1;
}

///> I also added the **BCT_CLAN**
```

I believe those values, 0x000000 for example, are some 32 bit-type of value which determines what the mouse player has their mouse over? This code is server-side so it sends a response to the client about what to make the mouse cursor etc.

My question is how would I go about finding out what those values are? Is it something you look for in the .exe? I checked every other .cpp and .hpp file and have been able to find that value anywhere. Does anyone have any idea where I should be looking?

Comment: "My question is how would I go about finding out what those values are?" - Do you mean the type of the values? I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: those look like masks. If that is the case you can't use `0x300000`, it will mess up everyting.

Comment: Yea the type of values.

Comment: The first block of code that you've shown appears to be a long variable declaration statement split over several lines, and the type is simply `battle_check_target`. Values such as 0x000000 are int literals.

Comment: I know this is a long shot but do you have any idea where I could find where that relates to when it comes to Clans.

"BCT_SAMEGUILD   = 0x200000, ///< Guildmates, No Guild Allies"

Must be defined somewhere else in some other file right?

Answer (score 0):

Skipping trailing 0 for explanation.

Those value are flag for bit:

```
Name            | hex  | binary
BCT_NOONE       | 0x00 | 0b0000'0000 ///< No one
BCT_SELF        | 0x01 | 0b0000'0001 ///< Self
BCT_ENEMY       | 0x02 | 0b0000'0010 ///< Enemy
BCT_PARTY       | 0x04 | 0b0000'0100 ///< Party members
BCT_GUILDALLY   | 0x08 | 0b0000'1000 ///< Only allies, NOT guildmates
BCT_NEUTRAL     | 0x10 | 0b0001'0000 ///< Neutral target
BCT_SAMEGUILD   | 0x20 | 0b0010'0000 ///< Guildmates, No Guild Allies
BCT_ALL         | 0x3F | 0b0011'1111 ///< All targets
BCT_WOS         | 0x40 | 0b0100'0000 ///< Except self (currently used for skipping if src == bl in skill_area_sub)

// Dependent values
BCT_GUILD       | 0x28 | 0b0010'1000 // BCT_SAMEGUILD|BCT_GUILDALLY,  ///< Guild AND Allies
BCT_NOGUILD     | 0x17 | 0b0001'0111 // BCT_ALL&~BCT_GUILD, ///< Except guildmates
BCT_NOPARTY     | 0x3B | 0b0011'1011 // BCT_ALL&~BCT_PARTY, ///< Except party members
BCT_NOENEMY     | 0x3D | 0b0011'1101 // BCT_ALL&~BCT_ENEMY, ///< Except enemy
BCT_ALLY        | 0x2C | 0b0010'1100 // BCT_PARTY|BCT_GUILD,
BCT_FRIEND      | 0x3D | 0b0011'1011 // BCT_NOENEMY,
```

You add:

```
BCT_SAMECLAN    | 0x30 | 0b0011'0000 ///< Expected Clanmates, but same as Same guild or neutral
BCT_CLANALLY    | 0x28 | 0b0010'1000 ///< Expected Clan allies, but same as Same guild or guild ally
BCT_CLAN        | 0x38 | 0b0011'1000 // BCT_SAMECLAN|BCT_CLANALLY ///< -> Guild or Neutral
```

Which is more clerly not what you want

and with example in code:

```
if (!state) //If not an enemy, nor a guild, nor party, nor yourself, it's neutral.
    state = BCT_NEUTRAL;
    //Alliance state takes precedence over enemy one.
else if ( (state & BCT_ENEMY) // Has ENEMY flag
       && strip_enemy
       && state & (BCT_SELF    // Is self
                  | BCT_PARTY  // or party member
                  | BCT_GUILD  // or same guild or ally guild
                  | BCT_CLAN /*Added*/) // or guild(same as above) or neutral
    )
    state &= ~BCT_ENEMY; // Remove ENEMY flag
return (flag & state) ? 1 : -1; // Do they share at least one common "property"?
```

Idea was to add/change:

```
BCT_ALL         | 0x01BF | 0b0000'0001'1011'1111 ///< All targets including clans
BCT_SAME_CLAN   | 0x0080 | 0b0000'0000'1000'0000 
BCT_CLAN_ALLY   | 0x0100 | 0b0000'0001'0000'0000
```

But, in your case, trailing 0s make me thing that the extra bits are already used for other things... So not necessary possible to add new properties.

You also have to properly set those flags to variables...